# Wireless dropping out on a BCM4313

Tags: 11.10, wireless, broadcom

My connection keep dropping out: I have to click on my home wifi-network to disconnect and reconnect to the internet.

I tried to set MTU to 1500 as this post[1] suggest but my wireless keep dropping!
[1] http://mylinuxramblings.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/how-to-stop-ubuntu-11-10-wireless-dropping-out/

The following question did not help me either: [How do I stop my ethernet network connection from dropping?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46942/how-do-i-stop-my-ethernet-network-connection-from-dropping)

My config is the following, ubuntu11.10 on HP Pavilion dv6, wifi using a WEP key:

```
$ lspci | grep -i eth
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)

$ sudo lsmod | grep iwl
nothing

$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2c:27:d7:ad:ed:fd  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:0 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          Octets reçus:0 (0.0 B) Octets transmis:0 (0.0 B)
          Interruption:42 Adresse de base:0x4000 

lo        Link encap:Boucle locale  
          inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
          adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:2004 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2004 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:0 
          Octets reçus:149984 (149.9 KB) Octets transmis:149984 (149.9 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:2c:f4:02:e6:a8  
          inet adr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
          adr inet6: fe80::422c:f4ff:fe02:e6a8/64 Scope:Lien
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:335223 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:198348 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          Octets reçus:424664317 (424.6 MB) Octets transmis:22730432 (22.7 MB)

    $ sudo lshw -C network

  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 06
       serial: 2c:27:d7:ad:ed:fd
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c0404000-c0404fff memory:c0400000-c0403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 40:2c:f4:02:e6:a8
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.0.0-12-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:c4500000-c4503fff

    $ dmesg
[ 9532.203125] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
[ 9953.253505] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[ 9953.253529] ieee80211 phy0: brcmsmac: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: disassociated
[ 9953.253544] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled false, count 1 (implement)
[ 9953.253556] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:24:d4:6c:a7:60 by local choice (reason=3)
[ 9953.381894] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
[ 9953.381908] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
[ 9953.381989] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 9953.394242] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[ 9953.394257] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 9953.394265] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2417 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[ 9953.394275] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 9953.394283] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2422 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[ 9953.394292] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 9953.394299] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2427 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[ 9953.394309] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 9953.394316] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2432 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[ 9953.394326] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 9953.394333] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2437 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[ 9953.394342] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 9953.394350] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2442 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[ 9953.394359] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 9953.394366] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2447 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[ 9953.394375] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 9953.394384] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2452 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[ 9953.394393] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 9953.394401] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2457 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[ 9953.394410] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 9953.394418] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2462 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[ 9953.394428] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 9953.394435] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2467 MHz
[ 9953.394441] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2472 MHz
[ 9953.394447] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2484 MHz
[ 9953.394457] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 9953.394462] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 9953.394472] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 9953.394481] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 9953.394491] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 9953.394500] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 9953.394509] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 9954.078437] wlan0: authenticate with 00:24:d4:6c:a7:60 (try 1)
[ 9954.080078] wlan0: authenticated
[ 9954.080674] wlan0: associate with 00:24:d4:6c:a7:60 (try 1)
[ 9954.084134] wlan0: RX ReassocResp from 00:24:d4:6c:a7:60 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[ 9954.084146] wlan0: associated
[ 9954.084733] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[ 9954.084753] ieee80211 phy0: brcmsmac: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
[ 9954.084775] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled true, count 0 (implement)
[ 9954.178608] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled true, count 1 (implement)
[ 9964.500026] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
[10129.310209] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 4
[10129.315119] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[10129.316770] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[10129.318072] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[10129.324147] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 4
[10129.324150] psmouse.c: issuing reconnect request
[10295.864340] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[10295.864364] ieee80211 phy0: brcmsmac: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: disassociated
[10295.864378] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled false, count 1 (implement)
[10295.864389] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:24:d4:6c:a7:60 by local choice (reason=3)
[10295.996982] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
[10295.996997] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
[10295.997039] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[10296.007372] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10296.007387] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10296.007395] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2417 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10296.007405] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10296.007413] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2422 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10296.007423] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10296.007431] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2427 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10296.007440] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10296.007448] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2432 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10296.007458] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10296.007465] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2437 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10296.007475] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10296.007483] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2442 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10296.007491] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10296.007497] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2447 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10296.007506] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10296.007512] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2452 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10296.007522] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10296.007529] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2457 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10296.007539] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10296.007547] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2462 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10296.007556] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10296.007563] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2467 MHz
[10296.007568] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2472 MHz
[10296.007574] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2484 MHz
[10296.007584] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[10296.007589] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[10296.007598] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[10296.007608] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[10296.007616] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[10296.007626] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[10296.007635] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[10296.673333] wlan0: authenticate with 00:24:d4:6c:a7:60 (try 1)
[10296.675742] wlan0: authenticated
[10296.676405] wlan0: associate with 00:24:d4:6c:a7:60 (try 1)
[10296.679387] wlan0: RX ReassocResp from 00:24:d4:6c:a7:60 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[10296.679405] wlan0: associated
[10296.680038] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[10296.680059] ieee80211 phy0: brcmsmac: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
[10296.680081] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled true, count 0 (implement)
[10296.772424] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled true, count 1 (implement)
[10306.995486] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
[10959.473673] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[10959.473697] ieee80211 phy0: brcmsmac: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: disassociated
[10959.473711] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled false, count 1 (implement)
[10959.473721] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:24:d4:6c:a7:60 by local choice (reason=3)
[10959.606133] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
[10959.606148] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
[10959.606171] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[10959.619338] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10959.619353] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10959.619362] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2417 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10959.619372] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10959.619380] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2422 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10959.619389] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10959.619397] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2427 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10959.619407] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10959.619415] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2432 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10959.619424] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10959.619432] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2437 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10959.619441] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10959.619450] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2442 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10959.619459] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10959.619467] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2447 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10959.619477] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10959.619484] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2452 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10959.619494] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10959.619502] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2457 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10959.619510] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10959.619518] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2462 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[10959.619528] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[10959.619536] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2467 MHz
[10959.619541] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2472 MHz
[10959.619547] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2484 MHz
[10959.619557] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[10959.619563] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[10959.619572] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[10959.619582] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[10959.619591] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[10959.619600] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[10959.619609] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[10960.289297] wlan0: authenticate with 00:24:d4:6c:a7:60 (try 1)
[10960.290935] wlan0: authenticated
[10960.291233] wlan0: associate with 00:24:d4:6c:a7:60 (try 1)
[10960.294306] wlan0: RX ReassocResp from 00:24:d4:6c:a7:60 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[10960.294317] wlan0: associated
[10960.294932] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[10960.294953] ieee80211 phy0: brcmsmac: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
[10960.294974] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled true, count 0 (implement)
[10960.352994] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled true, count 1 (implement)
[10970.495396] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
[11087.098762] thunderbird-bin[21454]: segfault at 47a2f968 ip 00007f8d4e101c08 sp 00007fff100b9600 error 4 in libX11.so.6.3.0[7f8d4e0cc000+133000]
[11121.347726] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[11121.347751] ieee80211 phy0: brcmsmac: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: disassociated
[11121.347764] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled false, count 1 (implement)
[11121.347772] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:24:d4:6c:a7:60 by local choice (reason=3)
[11121.458090] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
[11121.458106] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
[11121.458159] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[11121.466926] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[11121.466931] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[11121.466934] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2417 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[11121.466937] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[11121.466939] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2422 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[11121.466942] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[11121.466945] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2427 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[11121.466947] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[11121.466950] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2432 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[11121.466953] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[11121.466955] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2437 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[11121.466958] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[11121.466960] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2442 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[11121.466963] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[11121.466966] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2447 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[11121.466969] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[11121.466971] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2452 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[11121.466974] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[11121.466976] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2457 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[11121.466979] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[11121.466982] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2462 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[11121.466985] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[11121.466987] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2467 MHz
[11121.466989] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2472 MHz
[11121.466990] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2484 MHz
[11121.466993] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[11121.466994] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[11121.466997] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[11121.467000] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[11121.467003] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[11121.467005] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[11121.467008] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[11122.126757] wlan0: authenticate with 00:24:d4:6c:a7:60 (try 1)
[11122.128357] wlan0: authenticated
[11122.128949] wlan0: associate with 00:24:d4:6c:a7:60 (try 1)
[11122.132048] wlan0: RX ReassocResp from 00:24:d4:6c:a7:60 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[11122.132061] wlan0: associated
[11122.132665] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[11122.132692] ieee80211 phy0: brcmsmac: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
[11122.132717] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled true, count 0 (implement)
[11122.209770] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled true, count 1 (implement)
[11133.139251] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
[12443.067973] thunderbird-bin[21693]: segfault at 4432f968 ip 00007fed4a977c08 sp 00007fffd1700aa0 error 4 in libX11.so.6.3.0[7fed4a942000+133000]
[12860.796445] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[12860.796495] ieee80211 phy0: brcmsmac: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: disassociated
[12860.796510] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled false, count 1 (implement)
[12860.796522] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:24:d4:6c:a7:60 by local choice (reason=3)
[12860.928592] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
[12860.928608] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
[12860.928619] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[12860.938395] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[12860.938410] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[12860.938419] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2417 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[12860.938428] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[12860.938436] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2422 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[12860.938445] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[12860.938454] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2427 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[12860.938464] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[12860.938472] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2432 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[12860.938482] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[12860.938490] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2437 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[12860.938500] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[12860.938507] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2442 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[12860.938516] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[12860.938522] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2447 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[12860.938532] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[12860.938538] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2452 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[12860.938548] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[12860.938557] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2457 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[12860.938565] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[12860.938572] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2462 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[12860.938580] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[12860.938586] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2467 MHz
[12860.938591] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2472 MHz
[12860.938596] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2484 MHz
[12860.938605] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[12860.938610] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[12860.938618] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[12860.938627] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[12860.938636] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[12860.938645] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[12860.938653] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[12861.604995] wlan0: authenticate with 00:24:d4:6c:a7:60 (try 1)
[12861.606814] wlan0: authenticated
[12861.607309] wlan0: associate with 00:24:d4:6c:a7:60 (try 1)
[12861.610404] wlan0: RX ReassocResp from 00:24:d4:6c:a7:60 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[12861.610415] wlan0: associated
[12861.611046] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[12861.611067] ieee80211 phy0: brcmsmac: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
[12861.611089] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled true, count 0 (implement)
[12861.687610] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled true, count 1 (implement)
[12872.562747] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
[12955.317191] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[12955.318831] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
[12955.330146] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 - driver resynched.
```

Edit: Trying [How do I get my Broadcom BCM4313 working correctly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12355/broadcom-bcm4313-working-but-terribly-slow/67806#67806)

```
$ lsmod | grep brc
brcmsmac              631693  0 
brcmutil               17837  1 brcmsmac
mac80211              310872  1 brcmsmac
cfg80211              199587  2 brcmsmac,mac80211
crc_ccitt              12667  1 brcmsmac
```

Comment: Have you blacklisted the Broadcom **BCM4313** default driver?
  see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/82885/hp-pavilion-g6-1250-with-a-bcm-4313-doesnt-see-any-wireless-networks

Answer (score 1):

I am somewhat confused; from the output of `lshw -C network` it seems you were already using `brcmsmac` driver before the edit:

```
   product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   [snip]
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac [snip]
```

If it is so, you should try the binary Broadcom STA driver, which sometimes work quite better than [this post suggests](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12355/broadcom-bcm4313-working-but-terribly-slow/67806#67806). You can install it using `jockey-gtk` (or Additional Drivers in menu) or with

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

You can check what driver is being used from NetworkManager menu (under Connection information) or again with `lshw` - STA driver is called *wl* so lshw should return `driver=wl` (or `wl0`) instead of `driver=brcmsmac`. `lsmod` isn't much of use here because both drivers can be loaded.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me http://drndivoje.wordpress.com/2011/07/31/how-to-enable-broadcom-wireless-bcm4311-card-on-linux-mint-11/