# Wireless connection keeps dropping randomly on Dell Inspiron N5110

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, dell, broadcom

I have Ubuntu 14.04.1 installed on a Dell Inspiron N5110 laptop.

I'm connecting to the internet through a wireless adapter, but when I'm connected I suddenly lose internet connection while I am still connected to the LAN and I have to disconnect and reconnect to regain internet connection.

My wireless adapter is  BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Tackling received signal strength: do you get a strong signal where your PC is positioned?
Have you tried plugging the PC directly into the router by cable, just to see if it is a 'wireless' problem or a router problem.
Does anyone move close by the router, and stay there, between you and the router, when it drops out?
Have you updated the firmware in the router recently?
Have you checked the Internet to see if any other people have the same problem with that particular router, searching for it by name and model number?

Comment: I am new to ubuntu, I was working on windows at the very same position and never had this problem and I still have windows installed when I use it I don't have this problem so I don't think its a router problem and I never updated its firmware and It's really hard to try the cable thing, any Ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wireless dropping out on a BCM4313](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73900/wireless-dropping-out-on-a-bcm4313)

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Apparently the b43 series has some problems with Ubuntu.
The link explains how to update your drivers for the WiFi card. 
I am writing from my phone so can't copy and paste all the details, but take care to use the commands specific for your version.
I hope it helps